# Data-table rendering directly from datasource without configuring the hardcoded columns (in ColDef) in .ts file

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-validation

Is there any possibility where the ag-grid can populate all the columns without hardcoding them in ColDef array?

I am expecting ag-grid to populate all the columns and repective data that are coming from the JSON file directly. I do not want to configure the column names in .ts file manually.

Comment: Something like this is probably best you'll be able to do automaticly, without writing your own code: https://blog.ag-grid.com/dynamically-setting-ag-grid-columns-from-json/